# Convert Local Timezone time to UTC

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, momentjs

I am looking for a way to convert a Javascript date object in local time assuming a timezone like `America/New_York`:

`2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z`

I'd like to convert this to a date object in `UTC`.

`2019-01-04T05:00:00.000Z`

```
const timezone = 'America/New_York';
const localMidnight = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 4)) // 2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z
moment.tz(localMidnight, timezone).utc().toDate()
```

Here this is still returning the same as the input `2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z`.

```
> m(localMidnight, 'America/New_York').tz('utc').toDate()
2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z
> m(localMidnight, 'America/New_York').tz('UTC').toDate()
2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z
> m(localMidnight, 'America/New_York').utc().toDate()
2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: Updated, I tried this is not working as well.

Comment: try `new Date(2019,0,1).toGMTString()`

Comment: or `new Date(2019,0,1).toISOString()` to get the format you posted

Comment: This question is confusing :-) A date string with `Z` at the end is already UTC, not local. Do you have an actual date object or a string? Why would you use `Date.UTC` to get a non-UTC date? An actual date object is already aware of its UTC time, use `.toISOString` to see it.

Comment: Are you really asking "I want to generate a Date for midnight in a particular timezone, then generate an ISO 8601 formatted timestamp using UTC"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was with the format of the date you created, in this example you can see that `.toISOString()` adds a *Z* at the end, and for the `moment.tz` method to work you need to remove that letter from the format.

Here's an example creating a new date in `'America/New_York'` and changing the time zone to UTC

```js
const timezone = 'America/New_York';
const localMidnight = new Date(2019, 01, 04);

console.log("Original time:")
console.log(localMidnight.toISOString());

console.log("Converted to UTC:");
console.log(moment.tz(localMidnight.toISOString().slice(0, -1), timezone).utc().format());
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't know what you think this is doing, but it seems wrong. I get "Original time: 2019-02-03T14:00:00.000Z" which is correct, then "Converted to UTC: 2019-02-03T19:00:00Z" which is wrong because the first string is already UTC. The second is just shifted 5 hours. The equivalent time in New York would be 2019-02-03T09:00:00.000-05:00. Or midnight at the start of 2019-01-04 in New York is 2019-01-04T05:00:00Z.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

**Syntax** - moment(date).tz(timezone).utc().format()

For format-YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ use **toISOString**() instead of **format()**

```js
const timezone = 'America/New_York';
const localMidnight = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 4))
console.log("newTime in utc",  moment(localMidnight).tz(timezone).utc().format())
console.log("newTime",  moment(localMidnight).tz(timezone).utc().toISOString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gZegqd?editors=1010

Comment: I get "*Error: Moment Timezone has no data for America/New_York.*". Your *localMidnight* is not local midnight unless the host is set to UTC, `new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 4))` creates a Date for 2019-01-04T00:00:00Z.

Comment: @RobG, fixed that error which was due to missing moment-timezone-with-data js file

Comment: You can remove *moment-timezone.min.js*. The code still does nothing useful, `new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 4))` creates a date for midnight UTC, not local. Using moment.js's *.utc* method means all calculations and methods use UTC and the default output format is ISO 8601. You'll get exactly the same result without moment.js and using *toISOString* instead.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is to create a date based on a date and time in a particular timezone, then create an ISO 8601 timestamp for UTC.

Comments in the following should be sufficient, but ask if you need more help.

```js
// Create a moment for midnight in America/New_York
var newYork = moment.tz("2019-01-04 00:00", "America/New_York");

// Create an ISO 8601 timestamp UTC
console.log(newYork.utc().format()); // 2019-01-04T05:00:00Z
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Note that calling *utc* triggers UTC mode, which has [*side effects*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) in addition to formatting as ISO 8601 and UTC.